# Script started by cron is unable to execute iptables command

Tags: linux, php, cron, crontab

i wanted to run cron file on boot and execute system command, everything works well, but if i'm calling iptables command with some arguments like:

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.161 -j DROP

command is not being executed because iptables is empty! i thought php script had no privileges to call iptables so i wrote in first line this code

```
system("whoami >> res.txt");
```

output in res.txt was root

my command looks like this in php file:

```
system("iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.161 -j DROP");
```

and here's my cron (from root user)

```
@reboot sleep 10 && /usr/share/php /root/myscript.php
```

in ps -aux | grep php it's visible that script is running and also, it works because it creates text document from first command if anyone knows anything about it help me as soon as possible please!

Comment: Why are you calling PHP to issue a system command, rather than just issuing the command?

Comment: php is processing some data and decides which ips to ban

Comment: so if i run file like : php file.php, everything works and iptables -L INPUT -v -n returns banned ips

if i will unban them and restart debian, and wait for ban,  iptables -L INPUT -v -n  is empty, php script is running that is visible in ps -aux | grep php
and also creates file res.txt because first line of  php file is :
     system("whoami >> res.txt");
and content of res.txt is "root" so i do not understand why script executed by cron is unable to ban ip and why script executed from terminal is able :/

Comment: The run environments are very different.

Comment: You should try putting the full path to iptables, as PATH is probably not what you'd expect when running from cron.

Comment: it worked, tnx <3

Answer (score -1):

Fixed, Solution was to put full path of iptables!